# Better way to write jquery drop downs and css changes

Tags: jquery

I am learning the jquery stuff and I am trying to figure out a better way to write the code that I created.  It currently "works,"   but I am using a .css string that isn't really functional as I get more complicated.  Here is a functioning fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/timlcooley/uuYa3/1/

and here is the code:

HTML

```
 <ul>
      <a href="#"><li id="basics" class="b1 grey_button" >Basics</li></a>
      <a href="#"><li id="advanced" class="b2 grey_button" >Advanced</li></a>
      <a href="#"><li id="combos" class="b3 grey_button" >Combos</li></a>
 </ul>

 <div class="clear basics">Basic</div>
 <div class="clear advanced">Advanced</div>
 <div class="clear combos">Combos</div>
```

CSS

```
li{
    list-style:none;
    float:left;
    margin:10px;
    color:white;
}
.clear{
     clear:both;   
}

#basics{
     background:green;   
}

#advanced{
    background:grey;
}

#combos{
    background:grey;
}

.grey_button{
    background: #adadad;
}

.basics{
     display:block;
}

.advanced{
     display:none;   
}

.combos{
     display:none;   
}
```

JQUERY

```
$('#basics').click(function(){
    $('.basics').css('display','block');
    $('.advanced').css('display','none');
    $('.combos').css('display','none');
    $('#basics').css('background','green');
    $('#advanced').css('background','grey');
    $('#combos').css('background','grey');
});

$('#advanced').click(function(){
    $('.basics').css('display','none');
    $('.advanced').css('display','block');
    $('.combos').css('display','none');
    $('#basics').css('background','grey');
    $('#advanced').css('background','red');
    $('#combos').css('background','grey');

});

$('#combos').click(function(){
    $('.basics').css('display','none');
    $('.advanced').css('display','none');
    $('.combos').css('display','block');
    $('#basics').css('background','grey');
    $('#advanced').css('background','grey');
    $('#combos').css('background','blue');

});
```

Here is an example of the CSS I will be changing which makes the format I am using not functional:

```
#basics{
    background: #60b263; /* Old browsers */
background: -moz-linear-gradient(left, #60b263 0%, #28d662 30%, #28d662 70%, #60b263 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right top, color-stop(0%,#60b263), color-stop(30%,#28d662), color-stop(70%,#28d662), color-stop(100%,#60b263)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, #60b263 0%,#28d662 30%,#28d662 70%,#60b263 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
background: -o-linear-gradient(left, #60b263 0%,#28d662 30%,#28d662 70%,#60b263 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
background: -ms-linear-gradient(left, #60b263 0%,#28d662 30%,#28d662 70%,#60b263 100%); /* IE10+ */
background: linear-gradient(to right, #60b263 0%,#28d662 30%,#28d662 70%,#60b263 100%); /* W3C */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#60b263', endColorstr='#60b263',GradientType=1 ); /* IE6-9 */
}
```

I am sure I have to use a 'this' statement, but I haven't quite figured those out.  I am not sure how to really use an .addClass, if those are the right way doing it.  Also the way it is in the fiddle it would be as if the first option is already selected on page load.  Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like your creating your own tabs and also using jQuery, why not use http://jqueryui.com/tabs/

Or you could simplfy slightly by using

```
$('#basics').click(function(){
    $('div').css('display','none');
    $('.basics').css('display','block');

});

$('#advanced').click(function(){
    $('div').css('display','none');
    $('.advanced').css('display','block');


});

$('#combos').click(function(){
    $('div').css('display','none');
    $('.combos').css('display','block');

});
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/uuYa3/2/

You could then take this further so the click function loads the ID of the  href clicked. Then auto local the DIV with the matching class.

```
$('a li').click(function(){

    var myId   = $(this).attr('id');

     $('div').css('display','none');
    $('.' + myId).css('display','block');
});
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/uuYa3/3/

Comment: Awesome let me check those both out!

Comment: Thanks for the link to the tabs feature i didn't know that existed!  that is exactly what I was looking for.